# Возможно ли использовать Facebook Audience Network в России?

Tags: facebook

Необходимо показывать рекламу **в** приложениях на iOS и Android. 
Если я все верно понял, для этих целей существует Facebook Audience Network.

Используя Facebook Developer Account я создаю приложение (имеется в виду приложение в экосистеме Facebook). Используя App Dashboard ищу карточку Audience Network и нажимаю там Set Up. Открывается страница на которой предлагается настроить Monetization Manager.

Monetization Manager необходим чтобы *подключить* мобильные приложения (те что на iOS и Android) к Audience Network. Его настройка требует создания Business Account'a.

Здесь начинаются проблемы. 
Если в процессе создания бизнес аккаунта указать в качестве страны Россию, то процесс настройки Monetization Manager'а заступорится. После указания страны, ссылки на приложение в сторе и тд появится окно (диалог, алерт) с текстом: "You won't be able to get Audience Network ads until your application is approved". Я ждал этого аппрува порядка 3х месяцев. Ждать бесполезно.

Если в качестве страны указать США, то Facebook даже не попросит указать ссылку на приложение в сторе и сразу предложит создать Property (Propery - один из параметров Monetization Manager'а).
После его создания откроется Monetization Manager где можно продолжить настройку.

Однако, один из этапов настройки Monetization Manager'a (точнее Property) - это указание банковских реквизитов куда должна перечисляться прибыль с рекламы (business payment account information). Если указать там реквизиты Российского банка то появится сообщение: "This platform isn't supported in this payment account's region."

Получается невозможно перечислять прибыль с Facebook Audience Network в Российский банк и соотвественно в принципе использовать Audience Network находясь в России? Это кажется странным, неужели на самом деле так? Должны же существовать какие-то способы обойти это ограничение (кроме открытия счета в иностранном банке... еще не понятно где в принципе посмотреть список поддерживаемых стран)?

Или может я вообще все делаю не так и есть другой способ получать рекламу от Facebook, показывать ее в своем приложении и получать с этого прибыль?

Comment: удалось найти способ? Столкнулся с этой же проблемой.

Comment: @user382320 На данный момент кажется что без друга в стране где официально работает Audience Network ничего не поделать